# A Vampire Data Analysis Program for the FWPD, Clojure for the Brave and True

Tags: clojure

I am trying to understand the program "A Vampire Data Analysis Program for the FWPD" at the end of the 4th chapter in the book "Clojure for the Brave and True". Here is the code:

```
(ns fwpd.core)

(def filename "suspects.csv")

(def vamp-keys [:name :glitter-index])

(defn str->int
  [str]
  (Integer. str))

(def conversions {:name identity
              :glitter-index str->int})

(defn convert
   [vamp-key value]
  ((get conversions vamp-key) value))

(defn parse
  "Convert a CSV into rows of columns"
  [string]
  (map #(clojure.string/split % #",")
   (clojure.string/split string #"\n")))

(defn mapify
  "Return a seq of maps like {:name \"Edward Cullen\" :glitter-index 10}"
  [rows]
 (map (fn [unmapped-row]
     (reduce (fn [row-map [vamp-key value]]
               (assoc row-map vamp-key (convert vamp-key value)))
             {}
             (map vector vamp-keys unmapped-row)))
   rows))

(defn glitter-filter
  [minimum-glitter records]
  (filter #(>= (:glitter-index %) minimum-glitter) records))
```

Can somebody help about conversions and convert function?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you realise that `(get conversions vamp-key)` will return a function, that will then be called on `value`, and that `identity` is a standard function (in all functional languages) that just returns the input it is given?

Comment: I think I understand now. (get conversions vamp-key) will return identity function or str->int function and than will call one of them on value. Thank you very much. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conversions` is a map, and as such contains key value pairs, called map-entries. `get` is a function that allows you to get the respective value returned when all you have is a key, and of course the map. So for `convert` to do its job then `vamp-key` must be either `:name` or `:glitter-index` (as they are the only keys on the map). Lets assume it is `:glitter-index` and that `str->int` is returned. Thus:

```
((get conversions vamp-key) value))
```

, becomes:

```
(str->int value)
```

So `vamp-key` is needed to obtain the correct function to `convert` the value. If `:glitter-index` and `"10"` are the arguments passed into the function then `10` will be returned.